# Results are not same while executing the code for more than one time on same excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA code to copy some set of columns from one book to another and then compare the data between two sheets from destination work book The code is working perfectly for the first round of execution But when I try to execute the code on same work book for second time by removing all the results and newly added sheets the results are deviating Please look into the below code and help on me where I am missing

I manually examine the results and the raw data.. the columns format is not changed but we click on the cell the data is adjusting and when I use the formula (v-lookup) it is giving the accurate result... But I am using the same V look up in my VB code as well...
    Again i tried with a new workbook (by assuming the work book got corrupted) with the same code and it is working for the first time and the same thing happening And also I tried  ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"to keep the cells format to general always.. But no luck

'Open value sets pivot and select the value sets by name
'Copy the list
'Open raw data work book and create a sheet
'Paste the copied value sets in the new sheet
'Compare the value sets with claims
'print the result in data sheet and remove the formulas

```
Sub Valuesets()

    Dim OpenwbV As Workbook
    Set OpenwbV = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Value Set Directory.xlsx")

 ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"


    Dim wspivot As Worksheet
    Set wspivot = OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable")
'Change value set

    Dim change_pivot_table
    Range("B1").Select
    change_pivot_table = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Value = "Observation"

'Copy data from PIVOT

    Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
    PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy
    Dim OpenWb As Workbook
    Set OpenWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Test_2018-11-15_SHEET1-Pass.xlsb")
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = OpenWb.Worksheets("Data")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Set NewSheet = OpenWb.Sheets.Add(After:=wsData)
    NewSheet.Name = "Valuesets"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Find last cell number of row A from data sheet
    Dim last As Double
    Dim Cell As Range
    With OpenWb.Worksheets("Data")
    last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

'Paste the copied data from PIVOT

    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("A1") = "Observation"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("A2")
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

     'Outpatient value sets-Comparision


Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("O1") = "Observation"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("O2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("O2:O" & last)



'Copy ED
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "ED"

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("B1") = "ED"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("B2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
 'ED value sets

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("P1") = "ED"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("P2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$B$2:$B$14,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$B$2:$B$14,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$B$2:$B$14,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("P2:P" & last)







'Copy Outpatient
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Outpatient"

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("C1") = "Outpatient"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("C2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
 'Outpatient value sets

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("Q1") = "Outpatient"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("Q2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$C$2:$C$72,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$C$2:$C$72,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$C$2:$C$72,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("Q2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("Q2:Q" & last)





'Copy Acute Inpatient
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Acute Inpatient"

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("D1") = "Acute Inpatient"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("D2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
 'Acute Inpatient value sets

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("R1") = "Acute Inpatient"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("R2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$D$2:$D$75,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$D$2:$D$75,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$D$2:$D$75,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("R2:R" & last)



'Copy Nonacute Inpatient
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Nonacute Inpatient"

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("E1") = "Nonacute Inpatient"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("E2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
 'Acute Inpatient value sets

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("S1") = "Nonacute Inpatient"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("S2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$E$2:$E$41,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$E$2:$E$41,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$E$2:$E$41,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("S2:S" & last)

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

'Copy Telehealth POS
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Telehealth POS"

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("F1") = "Telehealth POS"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("F2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

 'Telehealth POS

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("T1") = "Telehealth POS"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("T2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$F$2:$F$2,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$F$2:$F$2,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$F$2:$F$2,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("T2:T" & last)

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())




'Copy Online Assessments
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Online Assessments "

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("G1") = "Online Assessments"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("G2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

 'Online Assessments

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("U1") = "Online Assessments"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("U2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$G$2:$G$3,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$G$2:$G$3,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$G$2:$G$3,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("U2:U" & last)

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

'Copy Telehealth Modifier
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Telehealth Modifier "

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("H1") = "Telehealth Modifier "
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("H2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

 'Telehealth Modifier

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("V1") = "Telehealth Modifier"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("V2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$H$2:$H$3,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$H$2:$H$3,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$H$2:$H$3,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("V2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("V2:V" & last)

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())







'Copy Telephone Visits
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Telephone Visits"

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("I1") = "Telephone Visits "
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("I2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

 'Telephone Visits

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("W1") = "Telehealth Modifier"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("W2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$I$2:$I$7,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$I$2:$I$7,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$I$2:$I$7,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("W2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("W2:W" & last)









'Copy Diabetes
    OpenwbV.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Diabetes"

  Set PivotTable = wspivot.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("J1") = "Diabetes"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("J2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

 'Diabetes

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("X1") = "Diabetes"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("X2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Valuesets!$J$2:$J$305,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Valuesets!$J$2:$J$305,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Valuesets!$J$2:$J$305,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("X2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("X2:X" & last)


'Diabetes Medication Rage


  Dim OpenNDC As Workbook
    Set OpenNDC = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\skallakuri\Desktop\HEDIS-2019-NDC.xlsx")

    Dim wspivot1 As Worksheet
    Set wspivot1 = OpenNDC.Worksheets("PivotTable")

    'Change value set

    Dim change_pivot_table1
    Range("B1").Select
    change_pivot_table1 = ActiveCell.Value



OpenNDC.Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate
    wspivot1.PivotTables(1).ClearAllFilters
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = "Diabetes Medications"

  Set PivotTable1 = wspivot1.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable1.DataBodyRange.Copy

 OpenWb.Worksheets("Valuesets").Activate


    Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("K1") = "Diabetes Medications"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Valuesets").Range("K2")

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

 'Diabetes

Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("Y1") = "Diabetes Medications"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("Y2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(J2,Valuesets!$K$2:$K$1184,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("Y2").AutoFill Destination:=Application.Worksheets("Data").Range("Y2:Y" & last)

wsData.UsedRange.Value = wsData.UsedRange.Value

MsgBox "Execution completed"


End Sub
```

Comment: Hey I just Updated the file locations and names with test and master

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved....
Issue with: While dealing with Alpha numeric values and even for numbers, the system is properly comparing the data but when the columns format is changed to text it is working perfectly

Note: Specif columns are converted to text instead of whole sheet because we will have dates in the sheet(if date are converted to text from general it gives some numbers)

```
'Syntax for changing format to text
wsData.Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "@"
```

I Hope this may be helpful to some one else